# Read name of directory created using ansible's tempfile module

Tags: ansible

I wrote a simple ansible script to create a temporary directory and want to save the name of this directory into a variable. My `.yml` file is:

```
- hosts: " {{ lookup('env', 'HOSTNAME') }} "
  tasks:
  - name : Create staging directory
    tempfile:
      state: directory
      suffix: staging
      path: "{{ lookup('env', 'HOME') }}"
    become: true
    register: output

  - name: print stdout
    debug: msg="{{ output }}"
```

The output from running the above prints a `dict`

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts tempfile.yml  

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Create staging directory] ***************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [print stdout] ***************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true, 
        "gid": 0, 
        "group": "root", 
        "mode": "0700", 
        "owner": "root", 
        "path": "/home/xxxx/ansible.Fb7rbKstaging", 
        "size": 4096, 
        "state": "directory", 
        "uid": 0
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

How do I get access to `some_dict['localhost']['msg']['path']`? I looked up the `hostvars` variable and do see my temporary directory in it, but can't figure out how to get access to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the [Registered variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables) section in the docs to get more details, from your example `register: output` you could access the path by using something like this:

```
 - name: print stdout
   debug:
     msg: "{{ output.path }}"
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize it was this simple.